# ZPL batch print ship label issues...memory limit?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

We have a web app that batches the ZPL for many shipping labels (UPS, USPS, FedEx) at a time. For some reason it will randomly mis-print where is just prints the barcodes, but nothing else. This usually only starts after about label 20 or so in the batch, and even then, it is not consistent in the labels after that. Sometimes it does it, sometimes it doesn't. It is consistent in that it does it to the USPS labels and not UPS or FedEx.

If we reprint just that label's zpl, it prints fine.

So I was wondering if there is some limit we're running into with batching. We send just one long zpl string for the entire batch, each label separated with ^XA....^XZ.

The printer is a GX420T.

Any ideas?

**Example mis-print** - I drew black lines on the barcodes to make them not readable for privacy
[image: example mis-print]

Comment: Do you have access to the raw ZPL sent to the printer?

Comment: @EdHayes3, yes, sort of. We store the zpl for each shipping label in the database. But when we batch them, we concatenate them all together. So we can approximate pretty much assume what the full output is. The commands at the beginning of the ship label is: `^XA ^FWN ^LL1218 ^PW812 ^POI ^LH0,0 ^LT0 ^CI28` and terminates in a '^XZ'`. Then we do print a carton content label: `^XA        
^PW812  ^LL1218  ^LS0` and terminates with: `^PQ1,0,1,Y ^XZ`. So this patter repeats: ship label, content label, ship label, content label....etc.

Comment: Obviously there has to be a memory limit ;)

Comment: If you're storing all the labels in the database first, you can go into it and validate that the labels which don't print correctly are stored with all the correct data? I can confirm that the more industrial printers will NOT run out of memory. I had an application that would print many hundreds of unique labels in one print job, through TCP/IP. Worked flawlessly every time. Similar situation as you, LPNs/Pick Lists, etc.. Although, the shipping labels were printed at ship confirm, not during picking. The legacy system did print shipping labels with pick labels with pick labels, no problem.

Comment: What's interesting to me is that the lines and barcodes are printing. Which means you are probably not running out of memory, as ZPL is being processed. Is there any way you can monitor the data being sent to the printer? Wireshark could monitor network traffic, but does not appear you are using network here.

Comment: @EdHayes3 yes, I have validated that the zpl in the database prints correctly. Also our application correctly does a reprint of the same label, which again gets that zpl from the database. I was also able to successfully replicate the same 72 label print job on one of our local zebra printers that was the same model as our client's, without issue. So I think it has to be some hiccup in the printer itself, right?

Comment: Ya, see if they have a spare. those things are pretty cheap and mission critical not to have a spare laying around.